# How to change height of bottom bar?

Tags: css, html

I have a website but there is a problem I can't change bottom bar height.
Tried it in CSS but really can't change it.
Can you help me?

As you can see, there is brown bottom bar. Thank you so much.

http://havana.royalmedia.sk/humenne/

Comment: Show your code what you tried

Comment: you want to change the height of bottom bar(which is containing links of fb and all) or you want to change the brown bottom border?

Comment: please tell in which css rule you want o change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add height property to footer (if I understand right what you won't):

```
 .footer {
            background-color: #120a06;
            border-top: 4px solid #a36830;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 100px;
            padding: 10px 0 0;
            position: fixed;
            text-align: left;
            width: 100%;
            height:100px; /*add this*/
  }
```

Comment: thank you, didn't see there is no height. But I need remove brown color on top of the top bar.
see screenshot please : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19898988/Untitled-1.jpg

Comment: `body, #page-wrap{
            height:100%;
 }` and height to this two elements.

Answer (score 1):

just remove height in .footer class.

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #120a06;
    border-top: 4px solid #a36830;
    text-align: left;
}
```

this will show entire data in footer